# Adding Create-React-App application in existing React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I use some part of React Typescript application (eg. Home and login page) and after that I want to use ReactJs application created using create-react-app.

I have to use existing React Typescript project for login part only and after login I want to add my React JSX project.

```
const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In the above code I am rendering my **App.js** instead of **App.tsx**

I am getting below error while starting application using **yarn dev**(same as npm start)

```
**ERROR in ./ts/CarrierLoadBoard/App.js
Module build failed (from C:/D Drive/Workspace/Test/CarrierLoadboard/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\web\Web\ts\CarrierLoadBoard\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (16:11)
  14 | 



render() {
  15 |     return (
> 16 |       <div className="App">
     |            ^
  17 |         <Switch>
  18 |           <Route path="/AdminView" component={AdminView1} />
  19 |           <Route path="/rfqUploadPage" component={RFQUploadPage} />
at Object._raise (C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:748:17)
at Object.raiseWithData (C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:741:17)
at Object.raise (C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:735:17)
at Object.unexpected (C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9101:16)
at Object.expect (C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9087:28)
at Object.tsParseDelimitedListWorker (C:\D Drive\Workspace\Test\CarrierLoadboard\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5269:14)**
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: TS and JS files could be mixed directly, maybe the error was caused by other stuff, could u show the main code in codesandbox?

Comment: Maybe try to rename your file from `App.js` to `App.jsx`?